# FAILURE: Build failed with an exception. Execution failed for task ':app:packageRelease'

Tags: android-studio, exception, flutter

I don't get where I am doing wrong !!

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':app:packageRelease'.

  > Failed to read key weather.jks from store "C:\Users\mdhvk\weather.jks": No key with alias 'weather.jks' found in keys
  >   tore C:\Users\mdhvk\weather.jks
- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with
  --scan to get full insights.

Here my key.properties

```
storePassword=**
keyPassword=**
keyAlias=key
storeFile=C:\\Users\\mdhvk\\weather.jks
```

Here my app level gradle

```
def localProperties = new Properties()
def localPropertiesFile = rootProject.file('local.properties')
if (localPropertiesFile.exists()) {
    localPropertiesFile.withReader('UTF-8') { reader ->
        localProperties.load(reader)
    }
}

def flutterRoot = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.sdk')
if (flutterRoot == null) {
    throw new GradleException("Flutter SDK not found. Define location with flutter.sdk in the local.properties file.")
}

def flutterVersionCode = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionCode')
if (flutterVersionCode == null) {
    flutterVersionCode = '1'
}

def flutterVersionName = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionName')
if (flutterVersionName == null) {
    flutterVersionName = '1.0'
}

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply from: "$flutterRoot/packages/flutter_tools/gradle/flutter.gradle"

def keystoreProperties = new Properties()
def keystorePropertiesFile = rootProject.file('key.properties')
if (keystorePropertiesFile.exists()) {
    keystoreProperties.load(new FileInputStream(keystorePropertiesFile))
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28

    lintOptions {
        disable 'InvalidPackage'
    }

    defaultConfig {
        // TODO: Specify your own unique Application ID (https://developer.android.com/studio/build/application-id.html).
        applicationId "co.mdhv.weather"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode flutterVersionCode.toInteger()
        versionName flutterVersionName
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    signingConfigs {
        release {
            keyAlias keystoreProperties['keyAlias']
            keyPassword keystoreProperties['keyPassword']
            storeFile file(keystoreProperties['storeFile'])
            storePassword keystoreProperties['storePassword']
        }
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            // TODO: Add your own signing config for the release build.
            // Signing with the debug keys for now, so `flutter run --release` works.
            signingConfig signingConfigs.release
        }
    }
}

flutter {
    source '../..'
}

dependencies {
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:runner:1.1.0-alpha4'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.1.0-alpha4'
}
```

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':app:packageRelease'.

  > Failed to read key weather.jks from store "C:\Users\mdhvk\weather.jks": No key with alias 'weather.jks' found in keys
  >   tore C:\Users\mdhvk\weather.jks
- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with
  --scan to get full insights.

Answer (score 0):

Rename **key** in keyAlias. As the file is called key.properties, it might be conflicting.

eg

```
storePassword=**
keyPassword=**
keyAlias=weatherApp
storeFile=C:\\Users\\mdhvk\\weather.jk
```

Comment: Now error - * What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:validateSigningRelease'.
> Keystore file 'D:\AndroidStudio\Clima-Flutter\android\app\Users\mdhvk\weather.jks' not found for signing con
fig 'release'.

Comment: Seem like the location has changed. Did you recreate the keystore?

Comment: Yes !! I recreate the keystore